# Uploading iOS App on App store developed with Material library

Tags: cosmicmind

What other precautions need to take care of, while uploading iOS app on app store developed by using Material Library
Thanking you,

Answer (score 0):

There are no precautions you need to take. You should not have an issue publishing an app with Material.